# Use Bean from an another module

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am creating a Batch application to put some data from a web-service on the database.
To do this I need to convert DTO's received by the web-service on utilizable classes. This is possible using some mapper defined in an other module.

When I tried to **@Autowired** the mapper I have an Exception and I don't find how to pass out.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.execution.batch.processor.UtilisateurProcessor com.execution.batch.jobConfiguration.JobConfigurationAbstract.utilisateurProcessor; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'utilisateurProcessor': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.execution.server.common.mapper.UtilisateurMapper com.execution.batch.processor.UtilisateurProcessor.utilisateurMapper; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.execution.server.common.mapper.UtilisateurMapper] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
**Caused by**: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.execution.batch.processor.UtilisateurProcessor com.execution.batch.jobConfiguration.JobConfigurationAbstract.utilisateurProcessor; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'utilisateurProcessor': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.execution.server.common.mapper.UtilisateurMapper com.execution.batch.processor.UtilisateurProcessor.utilisateurMapper; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.execution.server.common.mapper.UtilisateurMapper] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
**Caused by**: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'utilisateurProcessor': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.execution.server.common.mapper.UtilisateurMapper com.execution.batch.processor.UtilisateurProcessor.utilisateurMapper; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.execution.server.common.mapper.UtilisateurMapper] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
**Caused by**: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.execution.server.common.mapper.UtilisateurMapper com.execution.batch.processor.UtilisateurProcessor.utilisateurMapper; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.execution.server.common.mapper.UtilisateurMapper] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
**Caused by**: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.execution.server.common.mapper.UtilisateurMapper] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

The mappers are working fine in their module. I can @Autowierdd them and use it without problems. And the my batch is working fine if I don't @Autowierd the mapper.

Someone have an idea?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

My configuration is on my job configuration class :

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.execution.batch"})
```

I tried to put : `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.execution.batch", "com.execution.serve"})`

But if I do that I have errors reported to the injection of the job's bean :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory com.execution.batch.jobConfiguration.JobConfigurationAbstract.stepBuilderFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stepBuilders' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory]: Factory method 'stepBuilders' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in com.execution.batch.jobConfiguration.JobConfiguration: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory com.execution.batch.jobConfiguration.JobConfigurationAbstract.stepBuilderFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stepBuilders' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory]: Factory method 'stepBuilders' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in com.execution.batch.jobConfiguration.JobConfiguration: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stepBuilders' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/SimpleBatchConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory]: Factory method 'stepBuilders' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in com.execution.batch.jobConfiguration.JobConfiguration: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in com.execution.batch.jobConfiguration.JobConfiguration: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Like I said, separately the to modules work fine.

- when I scan the server and the batch module the scan of the batch don't work.
- When I scan just the batch module, the server module don't work because isn't scan I think.

Comment: Can you provide your configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Since your configurations work independently, there is a good change that you have conflicting names in both packages. Which could result that configurations or beans are overwritten.

E.g.

```
package com.x;
@Configuration
public class AConfiguration {
}

package com.y;
@Configuration
public class AConfiguration {
}
```

As the beanname in the springcontext, only the class name is used without the package. So, if you scan both packages, only an Configuration-Class will actually be processed. The same  is also valid for classes annotated with @Component.

It is important to understand, that @Component and @Configuration classes are also instantiated as beans, with the simple  classname as beanname.

Also with @Bean annoted methods are a potential source of errors. If you have the same methodname in two different Configuration-Beans, only one will be instantiated.

Moreover, if you use as @Bean methodname the same name as a @Configuration class name has, then again, one is overwritten by the other.

Comment: The configuration use on the other projet is a xml configuration. And no bean or class have the same name.

Comment: how to you add the xml-configuration of the "other project" to the JavaApi configuration? Are you using `@ImportResource`?

Comment: I tired puting "@ImportResource("classpath*:root-applicationContext.xml")"
In the configuration-job class or in the Application class (main), steel don't working.
The other project "serve" is a war, this can be a problem?

Comment: As long as the war is in the classpath and the path defined in the @ImportResource is correct, I would assume that it works. But in order to narrow down the problem, it would probably wise to try to extract everything from the war, especially the xml configuration and add it directly into your project. Once that works correctly, you can work backward, putting the "server" classes back into the war and adding the server war again to your classpath (removing the xml still directly in your project) and then as a next step, but the xml back into the war.

Comment: The War is in the classpath, and I don't need to do all this decomposition because this war is part of the same project (I have the source code). When I run the project the server module work's fine! But when I just run the batch application the server module don't work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have forgotten to set the "scanner" with the appropriate package of the class that you want.

Your bean is `utilisateurProcessor`, fqn is `com.execution.batch.processor.UtilisateurProcessor`. Is it configured as a @Component or in your XML?

Please paste the spring' config, to see if you have added `com.execution.server.common.mapper` to Spring's scanner.

Comment: You can see my configuration now : I use @ComponentScan.

Comment: try this: @ComponentScan("com.execution.batch")